Approximation of $1/2$ by fractional parts
Let $\{u\}$ denote the fractional part of a real $u \geq 0$, and
$\mathbb{N} = \{0, 1, 2, \dots\}$.
For positive integer $N$, define
$$
T_N(x) = \sup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \min_{m \in [kN, (k+1)N) \cap \mathbb{N}}~
\big|\{mx\} - \tfrac{1}{2}\big|.
$$
My question is whether or not the following claim is true:

For every $x \in (0, 1/2)$, there exists a positive integer $N$ such that $T_N(x) < 1/2$.

If we assume $x \in (0, 1/2) \cap \mathbb{Q}$, the claim holds: write $x = p/q$ for integers $p \geq 1, q \geq 3$ and note
$$
T_q(x) \leq \sup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} |\{(kq+1)x\} - 1/2| = 
|x - 1/2| < 1/2.
$$
Therefore, I need to understand what happens for irrational $x \in (0, 1/2)$. I know that in this case $(\{mx\})_{m \geq 1}$ forms a dense subset of $[0, 1]$, but I don't see how this immediately implies the claim (certainly seems related).

Yes: indeed $N=2$ works for all $x\in(0,\frac12)$, with $T_2(x) \le \frac12-\frac x2$. To prove this, we must show that
$$
\min\Big( \big| \{2kx\} - \tfrac12 \bigr|, \big| \{(2k+1)x\} - \tfrac12 \bigr| \Big) \le \tfrac12-\tfrac x2
$$
for every integer $k\ge1$. If $\big| \{2kx\} - \tfrac12 \bigr| \le \frac12-\frac x2$ then we're done. Otherwise either $\{2kx\} - \frac12 > \frac12-\frac x2$ or $-\bigl( \{2kx\} - \frac12 \bigr) > \frac12-\frac x2$; equivalently, either $\{2kx\} > 1-\frac x2$ or $\{2kx\} < \frac x2$; equivalently, either
$$
2kx - \lceil 2kx \rceil > -\tfrac x2 \quad\text{or}\quad 2kx - \lfloor 2kx \rfloor < \tfrac x2.
$$
But if $0 > 2kx - \lceil 2kx \rceil > -\tfrac x2$ then $x > (2k+1)x - \lceil 2kx \rceil > \tfrac x2$ and thus $\{(2k+1)x\} \in (\tfrac x2,x)$; while if $0 < 2kx - \lfloor 2kx \rfloor < \tfrac x2$ then $x < (2k+1)x - \lfloor 2kx \rfloor < \tfrac{3x}2$ and thus $\{(2k+1)x\} \in (x,\tfrac {3x}2) \subset (x,1-\frac x2)$. Either way, $\big| \{(2k+1)x\} - \tfrac12 \bigr| \le \frac12-\frac x2$ as needed.
By the way, stating this problem and solution becomes much easier if we use $\|y\| = \min\{ |y-n|\colon n\in\Bbb Z\}$, the natural metric on $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z$, since $\|y\| = \frac12-|\{y\}-\frac12|$. In this notation we're simply asking whether
$$
\inf_{k\ge0} \max_{m\in[kN,(k+1)N)\cap\Bbb N} \|mx\| > 0,
$$
and the proof that $N=2$ works is a simple application of the triangle inequality
$$
x = \|x\| = \|(2k+1)x-2kx\| \le \|(2k+1)x\| + \|{-}2kx\| = \|(2k+1)x\| + \|2kx\|,
$$
so that at least one of $\|(2k+1)x\|$ and $\|2kx\|$ is at least $\frac x2$.

Yes, your formulation is a lot more natural, since the point is that we are really asking for ${mx}$ to be bounded away from both $0$ and $1$, which is what your metric $|\cdot|$ is exactly measuring (for this problem). Thanks!
